# Use a Composable inside of a Modifier.clickable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using a `ListItem` and I want to show an Alert Dialog when the user clicks on it. I've read that one approach is to create a value of `mutableStateOf` and then call the `Composable` inside of an if of the value, but this doesn't work.

Here is the code, I'm using `Modifier.clickable` because `onClick` doesn't exist on `ListItem`:

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun UsersList() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(elevation)) {
        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text("List of users") },
            navigationIcon = {
                IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, contentDescription = null)
                }
            },
            backgroundColor = elevation2,
            contentColor = Color.White
        )
        LazyColumn() {
            item {
                val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

                ListItem(
                    text = { Text("Name",  color = Color.White) },
                    icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Face, contentDescription = null, tint = Color.White) },
                    modifier = Modifier.clickable { if(openDialog.value) { OpenAlertDialog(openDialog)} },
                    
                )
            }
        }

    }
}

@Composable
fun OpenAlertDialog(openDialog: MutableState<Boolean>) {
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = {
            openDialog.value = false
        },
        title = {
            Text(text = "Title")
        },
        text = {
            Text(
                "This area typically contains the supportive text " +
                        "which presents the details regarding the Dialog's purpose."
            )
        },
        confirmButton = {
            TextButton(
                onClick = {
                    openDialog.value = false
                }
            ) {
                Text("Confirm")
            }
        },
        dismissButton = {
            TextButton(
                onClick = {
                    openDialog.value = false
                }
            ) {
                Text("Dismiss")
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: You lack serious conceptual knowledge. Please refer to the docs, or better still, take [the codelabs](https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/compose)

Comment: And we wonder why folks don't like SO @RichardOnslowRoper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling Composables from a callback.
Instead put the composable along with other composable function calls surrounded by an if statement. Something like this:

```kotlin
val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) } // Set initial value to false so that dialog is not displayed initially
LazyColumn {
    item {
        ListItem(
            text = { Text("Name",  color = Color.White) },
            icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Face, contentDescription = null, tint = Color.White) },
            modifier = Modifier.clickable { openDialog.value = true },
        )
    }
}
if(openDialog.value) {
    OpenAlertDialog(openDialog)
}
```

This should work.
One thing I would like to add is that instead of passing the `openDialog` state directly down the hierarchy, pass a lambda which updates the state. This will decouple the implementation of `OpenAlertDialog()` composable from the caller and increase its reusability (like if you want to perform some other operations when the dialog is dismissed, you could do that then).

Like this:

```kotlin
fun OpenAlertDialog(onDismiss(): () -> Unit) {
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
        ... // Similarly for confirm and dismiss button onClick lambdas
    )
}
```

And in the caller function, use

```kotlin
if(openDialog.value) {
    OpenAlertDialog { openDialog.value = false }
}
```